# Культура программирования

Tags: php

Хотелось бы узнать о культуре программирования в php. много интересует например нужно ли проверять например функции которые находяться в другом файле или проверять сами файлы есть ли они вообще и т.д. где можно об этом почитать?

Comment: http://getjump.github.io/ru-php-the-right-way/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обновляемый набор лучших практик:

http://www.phptherightway.com/

Перевод на русский (на момент написания этого поста отставал от оригинала на английском на год):

http://getjump.me/ru-php-the-right-way/

Answer (score 16):

Стандарты [PSR](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted). Обеспечат вашему коду читаемость и портируемость.
Принципы [SOLID](http://habrahabr.ru/post/208442/) ([wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))).
Классика: [DRY](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself), [KISS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF)) ([хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144611/) + YAGNI).

Что я хотел бы добавить конкретно про PHP:

- PHP, местамии, довольно ненадежный язык. Всегда используйте строгое сравнение (===, !==), кроме тех случаев, когда абсолютно точно необходимо нестрогое (==, !=).
- Покрывайте все, что возможно тестами: это действительно просто и экономит уйму времени на поиск ошибки.
- Если нет четкого ТЗ по какому-то компоненту, то пишите сразу с прицелом на расширение, делайте как минимум заготовки для тех методов, которые могут понадобиться.
- Всегда, всегда, всегда комментируйте код и обновляйте комментарии при малейшем чихе. Как только проект разрастется, вы скажете спасибо самому себе и автоматическому ввыводу этих комментариев в IDE.
- Проверки. Делайте их везде, где считаете нужным. Помните, что если они и начнут тормозить код, от них можно будет легко избавиться.
- Проверки #2. Всегда проверяйте входные значения (input) на соответствие ожидаемому. Если вас будут ломать, то в первую очередь будут ломать именно здесь.
- Проверки #3. Если ваша проверка не прошла - обязательно выведите соответствующее сообщение. Сэкономит миллиард нервов, когда какая-то из проверок вдруг упадет, а всего их десять, и непонятно какая именно упала.
- Логи. Если есть возможность их писать - пишите. Если напишите какую-то апишку - лог останется единственным местом, где можно будет отловить неисправность.
- Официальные доки по PHP не особо пестрят исключениями, но на самом деле это довольно мощный инструмент. Вместо trigger_error всегда создавайте исключение. Исключения можно наследовать; в PHP опять же это не очень часто встречается, но лично мне, например, удобно иметь целую систему исключений, в которой я смогу понять ошибку уже по названию класса исключения.
- Не стесняйтесь пользоваться чужими разработками. Помните, что отдельно разбросанные по вебу куски кода и классы обычно являются собственностью сайта govnokod.ru, а вот библиотеки, которые реализуют богатый функционал, имеют столь же богатую версионную историю и найдены на гитхабе, будут, скорее всего, очень полезны.
- Не бойтесь писать классы, не ведитесь на призывы оптимизировать код, пока он не работает. Обычно первая проблема научившегося писать новичка - это чрезмерная оптимизация там, где она не нужна, боязнь писать класс из-за того, что он "долго грузится" и пр. Как только в голову приходят мысли реализовать компонент функциями или называть переменные покороче, чтобы побыстрее работало - гоните их прочь, помните, что самое главное в коде - его читаемость и несвязность (см. следующий пункт). Если вы можете вернуться к коду через три месяца, прочитать комментарии и понять, как он работает, то вы и оптимизировать его сможете тогда же. Если вы написали оптимизированный код, который невозможно прочитать, то вы его уже не сможете толком расширить.
- Пишите слабо связанные компоненты. База данных должна заниматься только базой данных, класс подключения по FTP не должен знать, запускается он на винде или на линуксе - если такой вопрос встает, то надо написать базовый класс и отнаследовать от него линуксовый и виндовый подклассы, чтобы загрузчик компонентов сам решил, какой ему нужен. Это позволит легко "вынуть" класс и заменить его, не ломая все приложение и делая изменения только в пределах одного класса (если например, внезапно сменится ОС на хостинге). (Вообще, с FTP пример плохой, но, надеюсь, понятно, о чем я говорю).
- Нет ничего страшного, чтобы набросать "примерный" код, который будет работать через раз и кое-как, чтобы сделать какие-то примерки. Однако он должен быть **немедленно** переписан, как только вы поняли, что вы от него хотите, потому что как только что-то начнет зависеть от его публичного интерфейса - у вас начнется dependency hell, и куча времени может быть потрачена впоследствии на переход на обновленный интерфейс.
- У вас, как у программиста, есть ограниченный набор ресурсов: концетрация, количество объектов в "оперативной памяти", усталость, свободное время. Ваша задача - писать такой код, чтобы использовать их по-минимуму - для этого и нужны четкие стандарты написания кода, минимальная связность и прочее - это позволяет направить ресурсы именно туда, где они нужны, а не распылять их по всему проекту. Проект может расширяться бесконечно, ваши физические возможности - нет.
- Читайте. Лучше всего - мануалы к фреймворкам: увидите, как пишется код, как структурируется, какие существуют методики, а главное, рядом будет написано что и почему происходит в том или ином куске кода.
- И самое последнее: в любом проекте внезапно может появиться разработчик или консультант. Пишите код так, чтобы он мог его без проблем понять: ясно и четко.

Comment: @Fike YAGNI -- XP (в сказке Twin Valley Kingdom под псевдонимом XB -- Extremal Bridging) неистребимо? Аминь

Comment: Ух, впечатляющий список!

Особенно поддерживаю слабо связанные компоненты и вредность преждевременной оптимизации.

Comment: да список конечно впечатляющий, а если написано комментатором имеет быть отдельное уважение.

Comment: поизучавши swift, реально круто было бы видеть php в таком виде как сейчас swift. протоколы, структуры,расширения  и т.д.